# Sending simple message to node.js from java class using java.net.Socket

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to send a simple message "Hi" to node server where I am using express and socket.io.

Here is how I am initializing my node server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
                socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
        });
});
server.listen(9001);
```

an I am trying to send the message from my java class as

```
     Socket socket=new Socket("192.168.9.132", 9001);
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     out.writeUTF("Hi");
     socket.close();
```

I am not getting any console log at the node server end about getting message from socket.
Help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

socket.io is a websocket, which is a different protocol/implementation than a usual socket. See the [**net**](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) library for TCP sockets.